# How to avoid unnecessary API call when working with NgRx

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an application with 2 menu item; Teams, Players. Whenever I toggle between them, I have to unnecessary api call even though I have the data in store.

Below is the effects file:
//auth.effects.ts

```
loadTeams$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.loadTeams),
      switchMap((action) =>
        this.apiService.teams$.pipe(
          tap(() => console.log('get teams request')),
          map((teams: Team[]) => AuthActions.loadTeamsSuccess({ teams })),
          catchError((error) => {
            console.log('err', error);
            return of(AuthActions.loadFailure({ error }));
          })
        )
      )
    );
  });
```

Below is the component from which I make api call

teams-list.component.ts

```
export class TeamsListComponent implements OnInit {
  loading$?: Observable<boolean>;
  error$?: Observable<string>;
  teams$?: Observable<Team[]>;
  retrySubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(loadTeams());
    this.teams$ = this.store.select(getTeams);
    this.error$ = this.store.select(getError);
    this.loading$ = this.store.select(getLoading);
  }

  fetchRetry() {
    this.retrySubject$.next(false);
  }
}
```

This line in ngOnInit cause unnecessary api call. `this.teams$ = this.store.select(getTeams);`

How can I prevent it so that it makes the api call one time when initializing the app?

Comment: You can solve this in the effect by first calling your selector, see if it has data, if yes, return your success action with that data, if not, do the http request and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
loadTeams$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.loadTeams),
      // read the actions$ for an load success event
      withLatestFrom(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(AuthActions.loadTeamsSuccess)),
      // no success event? no teams loaded, so go on
      filter(([loadTeamsAction, loadTeamsSuccessAction]) => !loadTeamsSuccessAction),
      // remove unnecessary action
      map(([loadTeams,]) => loadTeams),
      switchMap((action) =>
        this.apiService.teams$.pipe(
          tap(() => console.log('get teams request')),
          map((teams: Team[]) => AuthActions.loadTeamsSuccess({ teams })),
          catchError((error) => {
            console.log('err', error);
            return of(AuthActions.loadFailure({ error }));
          })
        )
      )
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the store after receiving the event, then filter out emits that already have a value in the store.

More info: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this/#enhance-your-action-with-global-store-state

```
detail = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(ProductDetailPage.loaded),
    concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectProducts)),
    filter(([{ payload }, products]) => !!products[payload.sku]),
    mergeMap(([{payload}]) => {
      ...
    })
  )
})
```